# How can I prove that $(x^3-y^2)$ is a radical ideal in $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$?

Tags: polynomials, ideals, finite-fields

In an algebraically closed field, it's easy to verify that $(x^3-y^2)$ is a prime ideal, hence a radical ideal. However, $\mathbb{F}_2$ is not algebraically closed. So how can I prove this?

Comment: Did you try the definition?

Comment: Yes but I found it's difficult to calculate this.

Comment: But $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$ is a unique-factorization domain and $x^3-y^2$ is an irreducible element, so shouldn't $\langle x^3-y^2\rangle$ be a prime ideal (whence it is radical)?

Comment: You don't need to assume that the base field is algebraically closed here.

Answer (score 0):

I was reasoning along the following lines but now am not so sure. RTP that if $p^r \in (x^3-y^2)$ then so is $p$. Clearly $r$ cannot be even, as a square in char 2 only has even powers (cross terms go). So it must be odd. If $r=1$ we are done (vacuously). The cube of a linear polynomial can't look like $x^3-y^2$ (just test all possibilities) and neither can any higher power. So the ideal is radical.

Comment: I'm not convinced by this myself. It shows that a radical of x^3-y^2 has to be x^3-y^2, which isn't quite what is wanted, but I think it is on the right lines.

Comment: I think this is the definition for radical ideal.

Comment: But I find elements in $(x^3-y^2)$ can have even powers for $x$.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I think the above isn't right. As you say, $x^6+y^4$ is in there.